eas build for ios: metro encountered an error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
I'm trying to run an eas build for an expo go app by running eas build --platform ios. It errors out of the build during the "Run fastlane" portion of the build.
This is the exact error:
❌ Metro encountered an error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting
› Compiling expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » EXConstants_vers.c
› Compiling expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » EXConstantsService.m
› Compiling expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » EXConstantsInstallationIdProvider.m
› Compiling expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » EXConstants-dummy.m
› Creating  Bui
› Compiling expo-dev-menu Pods/expo-dev-menu » expo-dev-menu-dummy.m
› Compiling expo-dev-menu Pods/expo-dev-menu » EXDevMenu_vers.c
› Compiling expo-dev-menu Pods/expo-dev-menu » EXDevMenuAppInfo.m
› Compiling expo-dev-menu Pods/expo-dev-menu » DevMenuRootView.m
› Compiling expo-dev-menu Pods/expo-dev-menu » DevMenuRCTDevSettings.m
› Compiling expo-dev-menu Pods/expo-dev-menu » DevMenuRCTBridge.mm
› Compiling expo-dev-menu Pods/expo-dev-menu » DevMenuLoadingView.m
⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » Wibet/Wibet » Build Phases » 'Start Packager'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » Wibet/Wibet » Build Phases » 'Bundle React Native code and images'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » Wibet/Wibet » Build Phases » '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
   To fix, go to: Xcode » Pods/abseil » Build Phases » 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders'
   Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ app.manifest\ for\ expo-updates /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wibet-fjxowylqaoovhbfcvrpmgwrqngkm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Wibet/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/EXUpdates.build/Script-46EB2E0005E760.sh (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')
▸ (1 failure)
2024-04-02 10:33:31.054 xcodebuild[45749:54455] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ app.manifest\ for\ expo-updates /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wibet-fjxowylqaoovhbfcvrpmgwrqngkm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Wibet/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/EXUpdates.build/Script-46EB2E0005E760.sh (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

Exit status: 65


I believe it's erroring out because "transformFile" is undefined (although, if the problem occurs later, please let me know). This seems to be a problem that has come up for others as well in the past when doing builds for iOS, and it seems to be solved by using the LTS of Node. I have scoured StackOverflow/Github/Reddit/Youtube, but no matter which LTS node version I use (14, 16, 18, or 20), I'm still getting this error when I try to build. The most recent comments about this bug are from 1 year ago, so there could be a new solution now.
I have installed Node version 14.x, 16.x, 18.x, and 20.x using nvm and did nvm use/nvm alias default to test each version, and tried building with all of them (removing node_modules folder and doing npm install each time). All produce the same error.
My .xcode.env.local file in the ios folder of my expo go app has the correct Node version in the "export" line.
I have tried opening a connection to SSL as outlined in some stack overflows (with version 20.x). This doesn't work either.
Here is details of my system:
System:
  OS: macOS 14.1.1
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
  Memory: 328.97 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.17.1
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.21
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.6.7
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/npm
  Watchman: Not Found
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.15.2
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.4
      - iOS 17.4
      - macOS 14.4
      - tvOS 17.4
      - visionOS 1.1
      - watchOS 10.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: Not Found
  Xcode:
    version: 15.3/15E204a
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 20.0.1
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli":
    installed: 13.6.4
    wanted: ^13.6.4
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.10
    wanted: 0.72.10
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: false
  newArchEnabled: false

Here's my metro.config.js:
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('cjs');

module.exports = defaultConfig;


Here's my babel.config.js:
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
      require.resolve("expo-router/babel"),
    ],
  };
};


If anyone has any insights and can help me with this issue, that would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

can you share your metro.config.js and babel.config.js?

@brentvatne just edited and added both!

could be related to cjs or the babel plugins. i'd try removing any config you're not sure about
